# golang test spy incorrectly comparing equality

Tags: go, testing, test-double

I'm in the process of learning go and am adapting a Java Game of Life example from [testdouble](http://blog.testdouble.com/posts/2015-09-10-how-i-use-test-doubles.html). However, the test spy I have written incorrectly compares equality of my `World` struct - the test passes when it should fail, since `output(world)` is not being called. What am I doing incorrectly?

Test:

```
package gameoflife

import (
    "testing"

    "github.com/google/go-cmp/cmp"
)

func TestZeroGenerations(t *testing.T) {
    generatesSeedWorldStub := GeneratesSeedWorldStub{}
    outputsWorldSpy := OutputsWorldSpy{}
    conway := NewSimulatesConway(&generatesSeedWorldStub, &outputsWorldSpy)
    seedWorld := World{}

    conway.simulate()

    correctWorld := outputsWorldSpy.wasOutputCalledWithWorld(seedWorld)
    if !correctWorld {
        t.Errorf("Output called with seed world, expected: %t, got: %t", true, correctWorld)
    }
}

type GeneratesSeedWorldStub struct{}

func (gsw *GeneratesSeedWorldStub) generate() World {
    return World{}
}

type OutputsWorldSpy struct {
    outputCalledWithWorld World
}

func (ow *OutputsWorldSpy) output(world World) {
    ow.outputCalledWithWorld = world
}

func (ow *OutputsWorldSpy) wasOutputCalledWithWorld(world World) bool {
    return cmp.Equal(world, ow.outputCalledWithWorld)
}
```

Implementation:

```
package gameoflife

type SimulatesConway struct {
    generatesSeedWorld GeneratesSeedWorld
    outputsWorld       OutputsWorld
}

func NewSimulatesConway(generatesSeedWorld GeneratesSeedWorld, outputsWorld OutputsWorld) SimulatesConway {
    return SimulatesConway{generatesSeedWorld: generatesSeedWorld, outputsWorld: outputsWorld}
}

func (sc *SimulatesConway) simulate() {
    // seedWorld := sc.generatesSeedWorld.generate()
    // sc.outputsWorld.output(seedWorld)
}

type GeneratesSeedWorld interface {
    generate() World
}

type OutputsWorld interface {
    output(world World)
}

type World struct{}
```

Comment: All `World` values are equal to one another. And why wouldn't they be? There's nothing in them to distinguish them. I'm not familiar with the cmp package, but native equality is [defined in the spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Comparison_operators).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When called `outputsWorldSpy := OutputsWorldSpy{}` golang assigned default value in `outputsWorldSpy.outputCalledWithWorld = World{}` and you assigned `seedWorld := World{}`. So they are same that's why test passed. If you want to handle that case, i suggest to use pointer.

```
type OutputsWorldSpy struct {
    outputCalledWithWorld *World
}

func (ow *OutputsWorldSpy) output(world World) {
    ow.outputCalledWithWorld = &world
}

func (ow *OutputsWorldSpy) wasOutputCalledWithWorld(world World) bool {
    if ow.outputCalledWithWorld == nil {
        return false
    }
    return cmp.Equal(world, *ow.outputCalledWithWorld)
}
```

Comment: Ah, okay, so to check my understanding, if I define a struct and don't assign any value to its members, they will be assigned a default value, hence the equality comparison passing? By checking whether the memory address is nil, we guard against the case when nothing has been assigned before checking whether the two are actually equal?